# Multisite - create plugin to hide deactivated sites from the sites overview

Tags: multisite

When looking at /wp-admin/network/sites.php I see a lot of deactivated sites. 
I like to create a plugin that adds a dropdown above the sites table to show all available statusus of sites, and filter upon select.

So, if I select deactived, I only see deactived sites, and if I select active, I only see active sites.

I'm not looking for a complete plugin here, just need some pointers as what filters/actions I need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This does not yet seem possible, due to the lack of filters to be used: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26580